# Ping from subnet over IPSec

Tags: windows, networking, subnet, pfsense

I have set up a distributed network as in the figure below. The subnet x.15.x is a remote subnet, connected to the internal LAN via IPsec VPN. The Firewall has 3 interfaces, one connected to the net, one connected to the x.2.x subnet and one connected to x.3.x subnet.

1. When I ping 192.168.3.25 from
   192.168.2.10 I get a response.
2. When I try and ping 192.168.3.25 on
   it's external IP address from
   192.168.15.50 I get a response.

However;

3. When I try and ping it from a client
   on the IPsec connection (e.g.
   192.168.15.50) I get a **request timed out**.

Am I missing a principal of IPsec networking? How can I get it to send data to the x.3.x subnet?

The firewall is a pfSense, and the servers are Windows Server 2008 R2. The tunnel is a IPsec tunnel through the internet.

[image]

Comment: I like the black cloud for the internet!

Comment: I'm confused.  When you get the request timed out, you are pinging from what IP to what IP?

Comment: Please **edit** the question and add more info. You will get better answers if you augment the question with the firewall hardware specifics, software specifics, and the existing tunnel specifics.

Comment: @Paul: The timeout occurs from x.15.x to x.3.x

Comment: I'm not familiar with the pfSense firewall but i'm sure there is some kind of log you can check to see why the traffic is not getting through.  Does the traffic get through to 2.x?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the logs, there is no traffic being blocked by the firewall. My guess is that the separate interfaces are causing an issue.

Comment: Let me guess, the tunnel is defined on both sides for the x.2.x network only, and is bound onto the x.2.1 interface on the firewall. So, the unidentified device x.15.1 has no place to send the x.3.x traffic.

Comment: Try adding a route on the x.15.50 device pointing x.3.x traffic to x.2.1.  It shouldn't work, and is not good practice, but it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that, because the two networks are on different interfaces on the firewall, the  x.2.x subnet and the x.3.x subnet will require separate IPSec VPNs to the x.15.x subnet on the other side.

---

Response to OP comment: *So if I migrate the x.3.x subnet to the same NIC could this work?*

It might, but I don't know for sure. If you mount both interface IPs on the same NIC, you will likely need to have two tunnels. But if you increase the size of the x.2.x subnet by making the subnet mask 1 bit smaller (255.255.**254**.0), you can put the x.3.x devices onto the x.2.x physical network.  It should work as long as you can update the VPN to have the smaller subnet mask. There will likely be other considerations, such as DHCP and the default gateway for the x.3.x devices. I suspect building a second tunnel will be cleaner.

Comment: OK. So if I migrate the x.3.x subnet to the same NIC could this work? alternatively, would bridging the 2 nic's make a difference?

Comment: It should, although it depends how you do it.

Comment: I ended up trying all of the above, and finally created a new IPsec tunnel between x.15.y and x.3.y - this works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a routing problem.

The firewall must route traffic for the x.15.y subnet into the tunnel, and it must route traffic coming out of the tunnel to the relevant subnets (this should happen automatically, since these subnets are connected directly.

In addition, the router on the other side must route traffic for both the x.2.y and the x.3.y networks into the tunnel.

At the moment it looks like the router on the x.15.y network doesn't do that. The timeout occurs, because the router on the x.15.7 side does not have a specific route and therefore tries to send the packets via the default route (i.e. into the public internet, where they are not routable and therefore get lost).

Comment: This isn't the route I took, though I think it may be the cause. For some reason my router wouldn't let me set up a manual static route between x.15.y and x.3.y. An extra IPsec tunnel between the 2 servers solved the problem and I can now see x.3.y from x.15.y